# Sorting rows alphabetically

Tags: r, sorting, apply

My data looks like,

```
A    B    C    D
B    C    A    D
X    Y    M    Z
O    M    L    P
```

How can I sort the rows to get something like

```
A    B    C    D
A    B    C    D
M    X    Y    Z
L    M    O    P
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 25):

```
t(apply(DF, 1, sort))
```

The `t()` function is necessary because row operations with the `apply` family of functions returns the results in column-major order.

Comment: +1 for compact solution, plus explaining why t() is necessary

Comment: Except the explanation isn't quite right - it's not column major order, it's that new dimensions are added on to the start, not kept in their original positions.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding our difference. `apply()` is building a matrix one column at a time, right?

Answer (score 6):

What did you try?  This is really straight-forward and easy to solve with a simple loop.

```
> s <- x
> for(i in 1:NROW(x)) {
+   s[i,] <- sort(s[i,])
+ }
> s
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  A  B  C  D
2  A  B  C  D
3  M  X  Y  Z
4  L  M  O  P
```

Answer (score 2):

No `plyr` answer yet?!

```
foo <- matrix(sample(LETTERS,10^2,T),10,10)

library("plyr")

aaply(foo,1,sort)
```

Exactly the same as DWins answer except that you don't need `t()`

Answer (score 0):

Another fast base R option from Martin Morgan in [Fastest way to select i-th highest value from row and assign to new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58504930/fastest-way-to-select-i-th-highest-value-from-row-and-assign-to-new-column/58505175#58505175) is

```
matrix(a[order(row(a), a, method="radix")], ncol=ncol(a))
```

Timings can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506442/fastest-way-to-sort-each-row-of-a-large-matrix-in-r/58559219#58559219)