# Fastest way to select i-th highest value from row and assign to new column

Tags: r

I'm looking for a solution to add a new column to an existing dataframe / datatable which is the i-th highest value from each individual row. For example, if I want the 4th highest value, the new column will contain 1.9 for the first row.

```
data <- data.frame(a = c("a","a","b","b","c","a"),
                   peak1 = c(1.1,2.5,2.4,2.1,2.5,2.6),
                   peak2 = c(1.2,2.5,2.4,2.1,2.5,2.6),
                   peak3 = c(1.3,2.5,2.4,2.1,2.5,2.6),
                   peak4 = c(1.4,2.5,2.5,2.1,2.5,2.6),
                   peak5 = c(1.5,2.5,2.46,2.1,2.5,2.6),
                   peak6 = c(1.6,2.5,2.4,2.1,2.5,2.6),
                   peak7 = c(1.7,2.5,2.4,2.1,2.5,2.0),
                   peak8 = c(1.8,2.5,2.4,2.1,2.5,2.1),
                   peak9 = c(1.9,2.2,2.4,2.1,2.5,2.2),
                   peak10 = c(2,2.5,2.4,2.1,2.5,2.3),
                   peak11 = c(2.1,2.5,2.4,2.1,2.5,2.4),
                   peak12 = c(2.2,2.5,2.4,2.99,3,2.5))
```

I've tried adding an index column and then select the value using a lapply function, but it returns a list in each cell and runs very slow on the real dataset, which has ~3.000.000 records. Ideally, i'm looking for a solution that solves this in a few seconds because this runs in shiny.

```
data$index <- lapply(split(data[,c(-1)],seq(nrow(data))),FUN = order, decreasing = TRUE)
rank <- 4
data$result <- lapply(1:nrow(data), function(row) data[row, data$test[[row]][rank]+1])
```

Answer (score 8):

I've updated my answer to provide three solutions; `fun2()` is in retrospect the best (fastest, most robust, easy to understand) answer.

There are various StackOverflow posts for finding n-th highest values, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/2453619/547331 . Here's a function to implement that solution

```
nth <- function(x, nth_largest) {
    n <- length(x) - (nth_largest - 1L)
    sort(x, partial=n)[n]
}
```

Apply this to each (numerical) row of your data.frame

```
data$nth <- apply(data[,-1], 1, nth, nth_largest = 4)
```

I made a large data set

```
for (i in 1:20) data = rbind(data, data)
```

and then did some basic timing

```
> system.time(apply(head(data[,-1], 1000), 1, nth, 4))
   user  system elapsed
  0.012   0.000   0.012
> system.time(apply(head(data[,-1], 10000), 1, nth, 4))
   user  system elapsed
  0.150   0.005   0.155
> system.time(apply(head(data[,-1], 100000), 1, nth, 4))
   user  system elapsed
  1.274   0.005   1.279
> system.time(apply(head(data[,-1], 1000000), 1, nth, 4))
   user  system elapsed
 14.847   0.095  14.943
```

So it scales linearly with number of rows (not surprising...), at about 15s per million rows.

For comparison, I wrote this solution as

```
fun0 <-
    function(df, nth_largest)
{
    n <- ncol(df) - (nth_largest - 1L)
    nth <- function(x)
        sort(x, partial=n)[n]
    apply(df, 1, nth)
}
```

used as `fun0(data[,-1], 4)`.

A different strategy is to create a matrix from the numerical data

```
m <- as.matrix(data[,-1])
```

then to order the entire matrix, placing the row indexes of the values into order

```
o <- order(m)
i <- row(m)[o]
```

Then for the largest, next largest, ... values, set the last value of each row index to NA; the nth largest value is then the last occurrence of the row index

```
for (iter in seq_len(nth_largest - 1L))
    i[!duplicated(i, fromLast = TRUE)] <- NA_integer_
idx <- !is.na(i) & !duplicated(i, fromLast = TRUE)
```

The corresponding values are `m[o[idx]]`, placed in row-order with

```
m[o[idx]][order(i[idx])]
```

Thus an alternative solution is

```
fun1 <-
    function(df, nth_largest)
{
    m <- as.matrix(df)
    o <- order(m)
    i <- row(m)[o]

    for (idx in seq_len(nth_largest - 1L))
        i[!duplicated(i, fromLast = TRUE)] <- NA_integer_
    idx <- !is.na(i) & !duplicated(i, fromLast = TRUE)

    m[o[idx]][order(i[idx])]
}
```

We have

```
> system.time(res0 <- fun0(head(data[,-1], 1000000), 4))
   user  system elapsed 
 17.604   0.075  17.680 
> system.time(res1 <- fun1(head(data[,-1], 1000000), 4))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.036   0.393   3.429 
> identical(unname(res0), res1)
[1] TRUE
```

Generally, it seems like `fun1()` will be faster when `nth_largest` is not too large.

For `fun2()`, order the original data by row and then value, and keep only the relevant indexes

```
fun2 <-
    function(df, nth_largest)
{
    m <- as.matrix(df)
    o <- order(row(m), m)
    idx <- seq(ncol(m) - (nth_largest - 1), by = ncol(m), length.out = nrow(m))
    m[o[idx]]
}
```

With

```
> system.time(res1 <- fun1(head(data[, -1], 1000000), 4))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.948   0.406   3.355 
> system.time(res2 <- fun2(head(data[, -1], 1000000), 4))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.316   0.062   0.379 
> identical(res1, res2)
[1] TRUE
```

Profiling `fun2()` on the full data set

```
> dim(data)
[1] 6291456      13
> Rprof(); res2 <- fun2(data[, -1], 4); Rprof(NULL); summaryRprof()
$by.self
              self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"order"            1.50    63.56       1.84     77.97
"unlist"           0.36    15.25       0.36     15.25
"row"              0.34    14.41       0.34     14.41
"fun2"             0.10     4.24       2.36    100.00
"seq.default"      0.06     2.54       0.06      2.54
...
```

shows that most of the time is spent in `order()`; I'm not completely sure how `order()` on multiple factors is implemented, but it perhaps has the complexity associated with radix sort. Whatever the case, it's pretty fast!

Comment: fwiw, `fun2` is faster than using `Rfast::nth` on each row. and can i presume that the complexity is bounded by radix sort's O(wn)?

Comment: @chinsoon12 I added a little profiling information for `fun2()` and changed my answer so that I don't make an explicit statement about complexity.

Comment: `m[order(row(m), m)]` is actually an incredible fast way to sort each row of the matrix without any external packages. can i have your permission to post this solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506442/fastest-way-to-sort-each-row-of-a-large-matrix-in-r and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063881/sorting-rows-alphabetically and then reference solutions back to here?

Comment: @chinsoon12 sure! it's really pretty amazing to see how flexible that is; I guess one needs `matrix(m[order(row(m), m)], nrow(m), byrow=TRUE)` for row-wise sorting, but only `m[] = m[order(col(m), m)]` for column-wise sorting.