# In R, sort each row of two matched data frames

Tags: r, sorting

I have two data frames with matching cells.

```
    v <- data.frame(c1=c(30,15,3), c2=c(10,25,2), c3=c(20,35,4))
    w <- data.frame(c1=c("thirty","fifteen","three"), c2=c("ten","twenty-five","two"), c3=c("twenty","thirty-five","four"))
```

I need to sort each row of both without resorting to (slow) loops. To sort `v` (which will determine the order of the other data frame too) I use the method recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063881/sorting-rows-alphabetically):

```
    v.sorted <- t(apply(v, 1, sort))
```

How can I manipulate data frame `w` so that it matches the sorted version of `v`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` with `order`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(nrow(v)), function(i) 
     as.character(unlist(w[i,])[order(unlist(v[i,]))])))
#     [,1]      [,2]          [,3]         
#[1,] "ten"     "twenty"      "thirty"     
#[2,] "fifteen" "twenty-five" "thirty-five"
#[3,] "two"     "three"       "four"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! Your solution works for row 1, but not the rest. Actually, the list that `lapply(seq_len(nrow(v)), function(i) w[i,][order(v[i,])])` makes is correct. Is `rbind` missing something?

Comment: @emagar Sorry, forgot about the `unlist` part.  It should work now.